# How to repeat a sequence of numbers in a column using awk command

Tags: awk, gawk

My input file contains data like this.

```
//address: 9050004 data: 1 id: 1 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 9050008 data: 1 id: 2 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 902e004 data: 1 id: 3 len: 0 size: 2
...
//address: 902e008 data: 1 id: 799 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 9096004 data: 1 id: 800 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 9096008 data: 1 id: 801 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 9097004 data: 1 id: 802 len: 0 size: 2
...
//address: 902e008 data: 1 id: 1599 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 9096004 data: 1 id: 1600 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 9096008 data: 1 id: 1601 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 9097004 data: 1 id: 1602 len: 0 size: 2
```

from the above data, `id` value should not cross 800. The sequence must be repeated like 1,2,...799,1,2...799.

so my output should be like below

```
//address: 9050004 data: 1 id: 1 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 9050008 data: 1 id: 2 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 902e004 data: 1 id: 3 len: 0 size: 2
...
//address: 902e008 data: 1 id: 799 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 9096004 data: 1 id: 1 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 9096008 data: 1 id: 2 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 9097004 data: 1 id: 3 len: 0 size: 2
...
//address: 902e008 data: 1 id: 799 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 9096004 data: 1 id: 1 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 9096008 data: 1 id: 2 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 9097004 data: 1 id: 3 len: 0 size: 2
```

Could someone please help me in getting the above one in awk command?

Answer (score 4):

To wrap back to 1 when reaching 800, you will have to recalculate that column as `((id - 1) % 799) + 1`, where `%` is the modulus operator:

```
$ awk '/^\/\// { $6 = (($6 - 1) % 799) + 1; print }' file
//address: 9050004 data: 1 id: 1 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 9050008 data: 1 id: 2 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 902e004 data: 1 id: 3 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 902e008 data: 1 id: 799 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 9096004 data: 1 id: 1 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 9096008 data: 1 id: 2 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 9097004 data: 1 id: 3 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 902e008 data: 1 id: 1 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 9096004 data: 1 id: 2 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 9096008 data: 1 id: 3 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 9097004 data: 1 id: 4 len: 0 size: 2
```

Note that in your expected output, the `id` for address `902e008` is 799.  This is not possible if you're restricting the range to [1, 799].

Comment: Why we need the modulus operator to reset counting...? What i miss ?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou You _don't_ need to use the modulus operator _if_ the IDs are strictly increasing with +1 on every line. I don't know if that's the case though, so I'm playing it safe and modify the ID based on the existing ID. If the file is re-sorted on, say, the address field, then this solution would still assign the same new IDs to the same address lines.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=" "}{i++;if (i<5) {$6=i} else {i=0};print}' aa.txt
```

just change i<5 with i<800

Testing:

```
$ cat aa.txt
//address: 9050004 data: 1 id: 1 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 9050008 data: 1 id: 2 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 902e004 data: 1 id: 3 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 9050004 data: 1 id: 4 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 9050008 data: 1 id: 5 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 902e004 data: 1 id: 6 len: 0 size: 2

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=" "}{i++;if (i<5) {$6=i} else {i=0};print}' aa.txt
//address: 9050004 data: 1 id: 1 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 9050008 data: 1 id: 2 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 902e004 data: 1 id: 3 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 9050004 data: 1 id: 4 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 9050004 data: 1 id: 5 len: 0 size: 2
//address: 902e004 data: 1 id: 1 len: 0 size: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl variant of @Kusalananda:

```
perl -pE 's/id: *\K(\d+)/($1-1)%799+1/e'
```

(numbers don't fit exactly with PO example)